# Connected graph with a minimum degree at least 3 and its line graph

Tags: graph-theory

Problem: **Let *G* be a connected graph with a minimum degree of at least 3. Show that L(*G*) has no bridges.**

Hello, is here someone who could push me a little in the right direction? I'm new to this all and got stucked. I don't really know much about line graphs, I tried to find something in english but I can't connect the dots.
All I know is that:

- the line graph is connected as well,
- the graph *G* has a cycle (or more than 1).

It also looks like that if the graph *G* has a bridge, then the line graph L(*G*) has a cut-vertex. It was suggested to prove that all dots of L(G) lie on a cycle but I'm not sure that it's true and I'm still clueless on how to do that. Every help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are almost right. It suffices to prove that any edge of the graph ${\rm L}(G)$ lies in a cycle (actually a cycle of length $3$).

Comment: @kabenyuk I'm sorry, I've been trying to prove it till now but I'm still clueless. I thought that I can try it with assuming that there's a bridge but all I got was that I'd get a disconnected graph. I know that there are cycles in L(*G*) but don't know how to show that every edge must be a part of it. Then I tried to play with the idea that a minimum degree of L(*G*) is at least 4 but it didn't get me anywhere as well. I'm definitely missing something. But thank you for the comment, I didn't notice that the shortest cycles are of lenght 3 and now I can see it in the graphs I tried to draw.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a graph in which each vertex has degree at least $3$. Let $v$ be an arbitrary vertex of this graph and $e_1,\ldots,e_s$, $s\geq3$, be the edges incident to $v$.

We know that $e_1,\ldots,e_s$ are vertices in graph $L(G)$. Moreover, these vertices are pairwise adjacent in $L(G)$ since they all have a common vertex in $G$.

Therefore $e_1,\ldots,e_s$ form a complete subgraph in $L(G)$ and since $s\geq3$ in this subgraph each vertex lies in a triangle.

I hope it is clear now that $L(G)$ has no bridges.

Comment: I'm d**b, I was doing everything but couldn't think of looking at one vertex only even tho I did exactly the same thing when drawing the graphs. It is clear, thank you!!